# Dynamic cleaning method

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic

The first condition is provided, but the changes cannot be transferred when I can not refer to the second condition parameters. Unfortunately the ref keyword cannot be used with params. How else can I provide these two operations?

```
 internal static void Clear(params dynamic[] ctrl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ctrl.Length; i++)
            if (ctrl[i].GetType().GetProperty("Text") != null)
                ctrl[i].Text = "";
            else if (ctrl[i] is string)
                ctrl[i] = "";
    }
```

Example:

After a registration, I want to delete the values in the text boxes with a single method.
Use:

```
Clear (txtName, txtsurn average, txtPhone, txtAddress);
```

The method will clear if it finds the Text property in the parameters.
This part works fine. If a variable is used while an object is being used, the new values assigned to the variable will remain in the method because we do not get a reference. This section can not do the job well, so I'm looking for a solution to it.
Use:
Consider the following parameters as variables of type string.

```
Clear (Name, Surname, Phone, Address);
```

This code will work but will not assign new values to the variables.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. What is the purpose of this code ? What you are trying to achieve and what issue you are facing? Please provide some concrete details.

Comment: If I get any object as a parameter, clear it if the Text property exists.
If the object does not have a Text property, clear the string.
Example: Clear(txtName,txtSurname,txtPhone);

Comment: Please read it first. When you don't understand, do not vote negative.

Comment: I wrote an example in the previous comment.
Now I wrote a little more detail.

Comment: However, I cannot explain this in more detail and my English is not very good. You may need to try the code.

Comment: `"When you don't understand, do not vote negative."` -- you have no control over this, only on how clear you make your question, and I do suggest that you strive to make it much more clear if possible.

Comment: I wrote for some of them, unfortunately, we do not see them at the moment, they have deleted their own comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with strings (or any value type really) is that *strings are immutable* and `param` values are always passed by value.  When you use `params`, what the compiler does is create an array of values to be passed to the method, so

```
Clear (Name, Surname, Phone, Address);
```

is converted to:

```
object[] temp = new object[] {Name, Surname, Phone, Address};
Clear(temp);
```

and since string references are passed by value, the original `Name` variable has no connection to the *value* that's stored in the array and passed to `Clear`.  Put another way, when `Clear` changes the value of `ctrl[0]`, the string stored in `Name` is unchanged (or more precisely, `Name` *refers* to the same string in memory).

One *option* is to have several overloads with various numbers of `ref` parameters:

```
internal static void Clear(ref object obj1)
{
   object temp = null;
   Clear(ref obj1, ref temp);
}
internal static void Clear(ref object obj1, ref object obj2)
{
   object temp = null;
   Clear(ref obj1, ref obj2, ref temp);
}
internal static void Clear(ref object obj1, ref object obj2, ref object obj3)
{
   object temp = null;
   Clear(ref obj1, ref obj2, ref obj3, ref temp);
}

 internal static void Clear(ref dynamic obj1, ref dynamic obj2, ref dynamic obj3, ref dynamic obj4)
    {
        void Check(ref dynamic obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType().GetProperty("Text") != null)
                obj.Text = "";
            else if (obj is string)
                obj = "";
        }
        Check(ref obj1);
        Check(ref obj2);
        Check(ref obj3);
        Check(ref obj4);
    }
```

obviously this limits the number of parameters you can have, but there's no `ref param` equivalent in C#.

That said, I do not see what the value in "clearing" a string variable is - if you want to settle for *just* supporting reference types then the overloads are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and your reply.
Yes I know that 'ref params' are not used together.
I was trying to find an alternative method without limiting the array parameter.
Unfortunately, we need to set a limit beforehand.
We have created a method that can do whatever I want by changing the last method as follows. However, limited parameters.